# Linewidth spreading to all canvas objects

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've got this problem where I add a lineWidth to one canvas-object and then all canvas-objects in the same canvas gets the same lineWidth. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(20,100);
ctx.lineTo(70,100);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I make the lineWidth only apply to one object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's state based. You have to reset lineWidth later on to the value you want for the next path.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9z3kb6mk/)

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(20,100);
ctx.lineTo(70,100);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fill();

ctx.lineWidth = 3; //this
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fillStyle="blue";
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: So you mean that If I want default lineWidth later I need to put lineWidth = 1;

Answer (score 1):

Change the lineWidth line to be:

```
var defaultLineWidth = ctx.lineWidth;
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
```

Then in the second drawing action, add this:

```
ctx.lineWidth = defaultLineWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to set

```
ctx.lineWidth = 0;
```

before calling `ctx.stroke()` again.